# not able to install pip install robotframework on jython 2.7.0 and 2.7.1b3.Getting error as "jython.exe: No module named pip."

Tags: python, pip, jython, robotframework

Could any please tell me which Jython package you are using where you are getting all the pip package too.
Or could anyone please share me the folder location.
Because whatever version of Jython I am using getting an error while running the command : “jython –m pip install robotframework” 
    Error: Jython.exe: No module named pip.

N.B: I have both Jython 2.7.0  and jython-installer-2.7.1b3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jython PIP is not a module you install separately, but an already included executable in c:\Jython\bin\pip.exe.

Answer (score 2):

You could try (and then use pip with jython):

```
jython -m ensurepip
```